# Empty space on Macintosh HD drive

Tags: mac, macos

Below is a screenshot for Macintosh HD drive storage.

[image]

It shows that I have 82.47 GB storage for "Other". How to delete and free up this space?

I checked `~/Downloads and ~/Desktop`, both are less than 2 GB.

I also emptied out `~/Library/Cache` and `~/Library/Cache` folders.

I am running OS X 10.11.2.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com) application (a free trial is also available).

This app help you to find out how you are using the space available and so you can identify what is occupying a large amount of space in your HD.